# Counting the actual used months in a range of Excel date values

Tags: excel, date, counting

I want to get a monthly average that only counts months containing a transaction.  Which is as easy as just summing all transaction amounts and then dividing by the number of months used.

I couldn't find a native Excel formula that would count months like that, and trying to sum over a criteria based on the ROW() function using a table or named range didn't work.  It would only return a zero when attempting to limit the count by year (or any other criteria).

That formula looked like this:

```
={SUM(IF(MATCH(MONTH(DateRange),MONTH(DateRange),0)=(ROW(DateRange)-MIN(ROW(DateRange))+1),1,0))}
```

That's an array formula, by the way.  It basically looks to see if the row you're on is the same as the first row that a month is referenced in a sorted list.  That's one problem with every method I've tried; the range needs to be sorted by date.

The greater problem arises when attempting to use an AND() or Boolean expression to limit the named range 'DateRange' to only the specified year.

So the question remains, how does one specify particular criteria in a single formula and count the number of months in a range based on those criteria?

Comment: Why are you asking a question if you already know the answer?

Comment: Well, every time I ask a question Stackoverflow asks if I want to answer it and "share my knowledge question & answer style".  And, since I had to come up with the solution myself when Google failed me, I figured somebody might benefit from knowing.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with is the following non-array formula using SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH('Transaction Log'!$A$3:INDEX('Transaction Log'!$A:$A, COUNTA('Transaction Log'!$A:$A)+1))<>MONTH(DateRange))*(YEAR(DateRange)=2014))
```

The trick is to compare the range of dates to a similar range, simply shifted by one cell.  So you would be comparing, for instance, cells 1:5 against cells 2:6.  Specifically, you're looking for places where consecutive dates are NOT in the same month, and counting them.

Unfortunately, this method is still predicated on having a sorted range.  But this way, you can specify any number of criteria to limit the scope of the data.  My old method of estimating average costs per month involved a simple ratio which drastically over-represented the monthly costs in some cases.